# How can I get value after hashtag from URL in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a URL and I want to print in my graphical user interface the ID value after the hashtag. 
For example, we have **www.site.com/index.php#hello** and I want to print **hello** value on a label in my GUI.

How can I do this using Java in Netbeans?

Comment: Information that you have provided is not suffiecient to me to answer to your question.

Comment: for example, suppose we have www.site.com/index.php#hello I want to print on a label in my GUI only the value hello. So, do you have any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: I am using java netbeans

Comment: Even tried to search for solutions .. before asking the question?

Comment: URIs have tricky escaping and encoding rules as soon as there are unusual characters involved (non-ASCII, or characters with special meaning). Therefore, I would not use any of the string or regexp based solutions you find here in some answers or at other places. Use a proper URI parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is [`getRef()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getRef()) in [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.anyhost.com/index.php#hello");
jLabel.setText(url.getRef());
```

**EDIT: According to @Henry comment:**

*I would recommend to use the java.net.URI as it also deals with encoding. The Javadocs say: "Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL()."*

and this comment:

*Why not just doing `uri.getFragment()`*

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.anyhost.com/index.php#hello");
jLabel.setText(uri.getFragment());
```

Comment: Why not just doing `uri.getFragment()`

Comment: I used : if (WGresult.indexOf('#') != -1) {
            wg = WGresult.substring((WGresult.indexOf('#')) + 1);  
        }

Comment: @Henry sorry, my bad it should be URL not URI and if it is URI your solution is perfect `uri.getFragment()`.

Comment: @Dima do not need to do much. there is a method called `getRef` I also didnt aware of this method before.

Comment: I would recommend to use the `java.net.URI` as it also deals with encoding. The Javadocs say: "Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL()."

Comment: I understand it now clearly, and I am reading doc right now. Thank you very much for being kind!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.split()` Method.

```
public static String getId(string url) {

    return url.split("#")[1];

}
```

`String.split()` returns an array of Strings that are delimited, or "Split," by the value you pass to it, or in this case `#`.

Because you want only the string after the `#`, you can just use the second item in the array that it returns by adding `[1]` to the end of it.

For more on `String.split()` go to [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm).

By the way, the part of the URL you are referencing is the Element ID. It is used to jump to an Element on a webpage.

Comment: I am not working on this URL, but I just gave an example to help you understand my question. Thank you anyway